# All Images & Extra Block Pop Up While Using Mouse Over in CSS3, When Only 1 Should

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get an image map working. I can't seem to get it going properly. I need to know where I went wrong here, and what I can do to fix it.

There is an extra empty box popping up and all of the mouse-over boxes pop up. The one that you are hovering over at the time should be the only pop up.

I would really appreciate any help

```css
span.drop_alaska {
  border-bottom: thin dotted;
  background: #ffeedd;
}
span.drop_alaska:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 6;
}
span.drop_alaska span {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999em;
  margin: 2em 0 0 0em;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1em;
  z-index: 6;
}
span.drop_alaska:hover span {
  left: 2%;
  background: #ffffff;
}
span.drop_alaska span {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  margin: 1em 0em 0em 0em;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1em;
}
span.drop_alaska:hover span {
  margin: 2em 0 0 5em;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 6;
}
span.drop_brazil {
  border-bottom: thin dotted;
  background: #ffeedd;
}
span.drop_brazil:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 7;
}
span.drop_brazil span {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999em;
  margin: 2em 0 0 0em;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1em;
  z-index: 7;
}
span.drop_brazil:hover span {
  left: 2%;
  background: #ffffff;
}
span.drop_brazil span {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999em;
  margin: 1em 0em 0em 0em;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1em;
}
span.drop_brazil:hover span {
  margin: 2em 0 0 5em;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="title" content="TSO Americas Sound Map" />
    <meta name="author" content="TSO">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mapcss.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
      <div class="americassoundmap" id="americassoundmap">
        <div class="americassoundmap_image" id="americassoundmap_image">
          <img src="http://40.media.tumblr.com/d8e8b561f67d2a68c2675b6e1baadb5f/tumblr_no76qlm55E1tyc2lxo1_500.png" alt="americassoundmap_map" usemap="#americassoundmap_map">
          <map name="americassoundmap_map">
            <span class="drop_alaska" title="alaskan_musician"><span>
            <div class="alaskan_drop" id="alaskan_drop">
              <area shape="rect" coords="12,42,85,76" alt="alaska">
              <a href="alaska_musician_link.php">
                <img src="https://www.science.unsw.edu.au/files/news/527C868C9284958A22F9E4D448BDDA12.JPG" width="200" height="150"/>
                <iframe width="200" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mLhXarmtndQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
              </a>
              <div class="biotext_alaska" id="biotext_alaska">
                <br/>
                An Alaskan Musician's Bio
                <br/>
                does anyone have anything to say about alaskan musicians?
                <br/>
                they might!!!
              </div>
              <div class="separator" id="separator">
                <span></span>
              </div>
              <span class="drop_brazil" title="brazillian_drop">
                <span>            
                  <div class="brazil_drop" id="brazil_drop">
                    <area shape="rect" coords="315,266,400,351" alt="brazil">
                    <a href="brazillian_musician_link_musician_link.php">
                      <img src="https://www.science.unsw.edu.au/files/news/527C868C9284958A22F9E4D448BDDA12.JPG" width="200" height="150" />
                      <iframe width="200" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mLhXarmtndQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </a>
                    <div class="biotext_brazil" id="biotext_brazil">
                      <br/>
                      An Brazillian Musician's Bio
                      <br/>
                      does anyone have anything to say about brazillian musicians?
                      <br/>
                      they might!!!
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </span>
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </map>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get it's pretty silly the way I have it set up. I just need it to work so that I can fill in the content and find the coordinates on the image map. If I am doing something wrong, I would like to know so that I can fix it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are multiple issues at play here.

Firstly, there was one structural error (no closing  tag for the ".alaskan-drop" div), but on top of that, the Brazilian section was nested **within** the Alaskan one. Was that your intent?

And Secondly, the reason the popup is occurring in multiple places is because your CSS tells any s under that "span.drop_alaska" span to appear whenever ".drop_alaska" is hovered over. That means **any** child span. This directly ties into the structural issue in my first point: because your Brazilian section is technically a child of the Alaskan one, it is subject to the Alaskan hover rules. Moving the Brazilian section OUT of the Alaskan one means that it can now operate independently.

Here's a clean-up of your original setup:

```
<map name="americassoundmap_map">
    <span class="drop_alaska" title="alaskan_musician">
      <span><!-- PARENT UNNAMED SPAN -->
        <div class="alaskan_drop" id="alaskan_drop">
          <area shape="rect" coords="12,42,85,76" alt="alaska">
          <a href="alaska_musician_link.php">
            <img src="https://www.science.unsw.edu.au/files/news/527C868C9284958A22F9E4D448BDDA12.JPG" width="200" height="150"/>
            <iframe width="200" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mLhXarmtndQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </a>
          <div class="biotext_alaska" id="biotext_alaska">
            <br/>An Alaskan Musician's Bio<br/>does anyone have anything to say about alaskan musicians?<br/>they might!!!
          </div><!-- end .biotext_alaska -->
          <div class="separator" id="separator">
            <span></span>
          </div><!-- end .separator -->
          <span class="drop_brazil" title="brazillian_drop">
            <span><!-- NESTED UNNAMED SPAN -->
              <div class="brazil_drop" id="brazil_drop">
                <area shape="rect" coords="315,266,400,351" alt="brazil">
                <a href="brazillian_musician_link_musician_link.php">
                  <img src="https://www.science.unsw.edu.au/files/news/527C868C9284958A22F9E4D448BDDA12.JPG" width="200" height="150"/>
                  <iframe width="200" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mLhXarmtndQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </a>
                <div class="biotext_brazil" id="biotext_brazil">
                  <br/>An Brazillian Musician's Bio<br/>does anyone have anything to say about brazillian musicians?<br/>they might!!!
                </div><!-- end .biotext-brazil -->
              </div><!-- end .brazil_drop -->
            </span><!-- END NESTED UNNAMED SPAN -->
          </span><!-- end .drop_brazil -->
        </div><!-- end .alaskan_drop --> <!-- THIS </div> TAG WAS OMITTED, I ADDED IT BACK IN -->
      </span><!-- END PARENT UNNAMED SPAN -->
    </span><!-- end .drop_alaska -->
  </map><!-- end map -->
```

(Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c34h2zex/)

And here's one with the sections no longer nested:

```
 <map name="americassoundmap_map">
    <span class="drop_alaska" title="alaskan_musician">
      <span><!-- PARENT UNNAMED SPAN -->
        <div class="alaskan_drop" id="alaskan_drop">
          <area shape="rect" coords="12,42,85,76" alt="alaska">
          <a href="alaska_musician_link.php">
            <img src="https://www.science.unsw.edu.au/files/news/527C868C9284958A22F9E4D448BDDA12.JPG" width="200" height="150"/>
            <iframe width="200" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mLhXarmtndQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </a>
          <div class="biotext_alaska" id="biotext_alaska">
            <br/>An Alaskan Musician's Bio<br/>does anyone have anything to say about alaskan musicians?<br/>they might!!!
          </div><!-- end .biotext_alaska -->
        </div><!-- end .alaskan_drop --> <!-- THIS </div> TAG WAS OMITTED, I ADDED IT BACK IN -->
      </span><!-- END PARENT UNNAMED SPAN -->
    </span><!-- end .drop_alaska -->
    <div class="separator" id="separator">
      <span></span>
    </div><!-- end .separator -->
    <span class="drop_brazil" title="brazillian_drop">
      <span><!-- (FORMERLY) NESTED UNNAMED SPAN -->
        <div class="brazil_drop" id="brazil_drop">
          <area shape="rect" coords="315,266,400,351" alt="brazil">
          <a href="brazillian_musician_link_musician_link.php">
            <img src="https://www.science.unsw.edu.au/files/news/527C868C9284958A22F9E4D448BDDA12.JPG" width="200" height="150"/>
            <iframe width="200" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mLhXarmtndQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </a>
          <div class="biotext_brazil" id="biotext_brazil">
            <br/>An Brazillian Musician's Bio<br/>does anyone have anything to say about brazillian musicians?<br/>they might!!!
          </div><!-- end .biotext-brazil -->
        </div><!-- end .brazil_drop -->
      </span><!-- END (FORMERLY) NESTED UNNAMED SPAN -->
    </span><!-- end .drop_brazil -->
  </map><!-- end map -->
```

(Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbg7sv86/)

---

(Sorry if that's kinda wordy, I couldn't post *just* the fiddle URL.) But **TL;DR: unless specifically excluded, CSS will affect all child elements, which is what your original setup contained**

Comment: this still does not work... i was almost positive my problems were from the CSS; but am unaware.

Comment: Strange, the second fiddle is working for me... (Only showing one popup). Did you make sure to update your HTML nesting issue?

Comment: yes i did, it is now working. thank you very much, i really appreciate it :D

Comment: by any chance would you happen to know how to reposition the pop-up boxes?? do i just use a fixed position tag in CSS and then place it via a fixed element / spacing in ems/pixels?

Comment: Anytime :) As for repositioning, it would depend on where you wanted them. Currently, they are "offscreen" and become "onscreen" when hovered. An alternate way to do it would be to have them positioned wherever you want them from the get-go, and then set them to "display: none;". Then, when hovered, change them to "display: block;" like so: http://jsfiddle.net/ymnves9y/